# Pass environment variables from pipeline job A to pipeline job B

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkinsfile, environment-variables

I passed params to pipeline B and set the environment variables from parameters. However, `"${params.URL}"` is evaluated as null.

Pipeline A is declared in `Jenkinsfile`:

```
pipeline {
    agent any    

    stages {
        stage('Run on all repos') {

            steps { 
                script {
                    sh 'ls'
                    build job: 'run-on-single-repo'
                    parameters:
                            [string(name:'URL', value:'val')]
}}}}}
```

Pipeline B is declared in `run-on-single-repo.groovy`:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {

        stage('Find missing dependencies') {

            environment {

                URL = "${params.URL}"

            }

            steps { 
...
```

Both pipelines are configured in Jenkins as 'Pipeline script from SCM' and work.

How to pass environment variables from pipeline job A to pipeline job B?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was missing comma between `build job` and `parameters`. Below is the correct syntax:

```
...
                    build job: 'run-on-single-repo',
                    parameters:

...
```

Comment: Is `run-on-single-repo.groovy` the Jenkinsfile equivalent for pipelineB? How do I pass in `build job: '<YOUR_PATH_HERE>'` command, if it is stored on a relative path?